# Extract function from beforeEach and assign to `this` variable

Tags: javascript, mocha.js

My `beforeEach` setup is extremely lengthy, and there is reuse between different test cases between different files.

Is there a way that one could extract the body of `beforeEach` and still assign to the `this` variable?

Example:

```
describe(function () {
  beforeEach(async function () {
    this.a = a.new(...);
    this.b = b.new(...);
    this.c = c.new(...);
    ...
  });
  describe("a", function () {
    it("calls a func", async function () {
      await this.a.func();
    });
  });
});
```

And extract the body of the `beforeEach` into a `setup` function (in a second file):

```
describe(function () {
  beforeEach(async function () {
    [ this.a, this.b, this.c ] = setup(); 
  });
  ...
});
```

Comment: Not clear what you are after... Extract the body a function and populate `this` are unknown concepts in JS. Try rewording your question to make it clear and include the desired result.

Comment: @marekful Apologies, I am new to JavaScript. I’ll make a few changes. The desired result is included (last code block).

Comment: You should move those functions to another file. Some `helper` file. Then, with module exports you inject them in the `beforeEach` in any test file you need. Another thing... assigning the values to `this` scope is not a good practice.

Comment: @manuerumx yes, assigning to `this` seems bad, but not sure I have much choice! I posted an answer, do you mind suggesting improvement, and I'll accept and close the question?

Comment: @isaacsultan You can declare a let variable just after the declaration of the first `Describe` perhaps the change seems small, but is a good practice to avoid the use of `this`.

Comment: @manuerumx Awesome, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//exampleSetup.js

async function setup() {
    const a = a.new(...);
    const b = b.new(...);
    const c = c.new(...);
    return [a, b, c];
}

module.exports = setup;

//tester.js

const setup = require("exampleSetup");
let a, b, c;
beforeEach(async function () {
    [ a, b, c ] = setup()
    ...
  });
```